# Find an example where a subset $A$ in an infinite metric space $M$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space and $A$ is contained in $M$. Find an example where a subset $A$ in $M$ is closed and bounded, but not compact.

This is my attempt:
Take the closed ball $B_r(0)= \{x \in A : d(x,0)\leq 1\}$. This is bounded and closed by definition but not compact (I think). I was wondering what infinite metric space I need to put this in?

Comment: Put it in $\mathbb R$, endowed with the discrete metric. It won't be compact then.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Thank you, that was much simpler than I thought! I'm not entirely convinced this is not compact- is it because any subsequence (i.e. another ball of smaller radius) would not necessarily converge to an element of $B_r(0)$?

Comment: It's because the open cover $\mathcal{O}=\{B(x,1)\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$ has no finite subcover. Actually, the only subcover of $\mathcal O$ is $\mathcal O$ itself. This is so because $\mathcal O=\{\{x\}\,|\,x\in\mathbb{R}\}$. Note: $B(x,1)$ is the *open* ball centered at $x$ with radius $1$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm not sure what you mean by finite subcover? Would you be able to give me an example of a metric that does have a finite subcover? Thank you!

Comment: I am using the definition of compaact. A metric space is compact when every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: You can all see the noncompactness of José's example by the fact that a sequence will converge in the discrete metric iff it is eventually constant. Taking a sequence with distinct elements will then not have a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @JohnGriffin So not every subsequence in A converges to an element of A? i.e. a ball with radius smaller than 1 wont necessarily converge to another ball in A?

Comment: A cover of $S$ is a family $F$ of sets with $S\subset \cup F=\{x:\exists f\in F\;(x\in f\} .$  A finite sub-cover of $F$ is a finite $G \subset F$ such that  $S\subset \cup G.$ The phrase "A finite sub-cover of $F$" can indeed be confusing.

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the discussion in the comments:

Take any infinite set $M$ and define the discrete metric $d$ on $M$ by
$$
d(x,y) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\ x\ne y, \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
The main thing to remember about a set with the discrete metric is that every subset is open. Also, when it comes to sequences, we have the following result.

> A sequence $(m_n)_n$ in $M$ converges iff $(m_n)_n$ is eventually constant.

Now the whole space $M$ is closed. It is bounded because for any $m\in M$ the ball centered at $m$ of with radius $2$ covers the whole space $M$.
However it is not compact. We can see this using either version of metric space compactness:

1) The collection $\{\{m\} : m\in M\}$ of singletons consists of open sets and it covers $M$. Since $M$ is infinite, no finite subset of this collection can cover $M$.

2) Alternatively, we can use the notion of sequential compactness (which is equivalent to compactness for metric spaces). Find a countably infinite subset $\{m_1,m_2,\ldots\}$ of $M$. Thus the sequence $(m_n)_n$ in $M$ consists of distinct elements, so any subsequence $(m_{n_k})_k$ of $(m_n)_n$ will also consist of distinct elements.
Since a sequence only converges in the discrete metric if it is eventually constant, we conclude that every subsequence of $(m_n)_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Did you interchange M with A? I thought we need to show a subset A of M which is closed and bounded is not compact?

Comment: @Enigma123 Let $A=M$. A set is a subset of itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider Usual Euclidean Metric on $M=(0,1)$. Now let $A=M=(0,1)$.

$A$ is closed , bounded , but not compact since the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}_{n \ge 2}$ has not any convergent subsequence.

Comment: Is M the open interval between 0 and 1? Just wanted to confirm notation. @Red shoes

Comment: @Enigma123 yes........